# Selected List Item Color Change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a Web page that contains the following code.

```
<script>
function changeColor(c) {
document.getElementById("message").style.color=c;
}
</script>
<p id="message">Welcome!</p>
<ul id="color">
<li>Black</li>
<li>Red</li>
</ul>
```

I need to ensure that when I clicks an item in the list, the text color of the Welcome! message will change. Which declaration should you use?

Comment: based on your question below.  do you want the color of the Welcome! to change to the color that the list element is, or the color that the list element says.

Comment: curious why the change of answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<li onclick="changeColor(this.innnerHtml)"> Black </li>`

Comment: thanks for reply, can i use use <li onclick="changeColor(this.innnerText);"> Black </li> OR <li onclick="changeColor(this.style.color);"> Black </li> instead of your code, pls suggest

Comment: Sujit if you use this answer letter for letter, it will not work.  Take a look at mine, if you need.  You may use `this.style.color` if you're applying CSS styling to the list element and you want that message to have the same styling, but if you want the message to be the color that the text literally says, then you have to use this innerText/innerHTML method.

Comment: Phil, what I meant by my comment is that your `innnerHtml` will result in two different errors due to spelling. 1) there is an extra '`n`'; 2) the "html" portion needs to be capitalized.  The property is called `innerHTML`.  Other than that, we were thinking the same thing, so +1

Answer (score 1):

***New:** [JS Fiddle using the font color (not text) and JS to attach the event](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/vVJt3/)*

---

[JS Fiddle of the Below](http://jsfiddle.net/cbFcK/)

```
<script>
   function changeColor(c) {
      document.getElementById("message").style.color=c;
   }
</script>

<p id="message">Welcome!</p>
<ul id="color">
   <li onclick="changeColor(this.innerHTML);">Black</li>
   <li onclick="changeColor(this.innerHTML);">Red</li>
</ul>
```

***Note:***

1. *This is not the best way to do this, especially if you have many list elements.  A better way would be to use JavaScript; get the `color` unordered list, loop through each loop element, and add the `changeColor(this.innerHTML)` to the click event.*
2. *`innerText` may be used instead of `innerHTML`*

Comment: so, it would run fine if i use                                      <li onclick="changeColor(this.innerText);"> Black </li>

Comment: yes it would run using that, I've added the new JSFiddle at the top, which uses the css font color (not text of what's in the list) and attaches the click event using JavaScript (*note: this is pure JS and may not be cross-browser*).  If you wish to use the literal text, then change the `document.defaultView...color` to your `this.innerHTML` - for some reason I thought innerText wasn't crossbrowser, at least I thought FF used to use textContent